# What is an szone_error?

Tags: xcode, memory, gdb

I see this sometimes in xcode console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is usually an accompanying error message when you get that output; it is a function you can set a breakpoint on to debug a `malloc()`/`free()` bug in your program.  [This thread](http://lists.apple.com/archives/carbon-dev/2007/Feb/msg00508.html) on an Apple development list has some more information.